# ConvertRecord Processor Removes attributes from json

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am using following nifi processors in order:

1. GetMongo
2. Jolt Spec
3. Convert Record
4. BigQuery Batch

I have mongo document with a specific fields let say "a" which can be null in some documents.Right now, My pipeline works perfect when i fetch all the record with the field "a" (in which it is there and is not null)
But the problem comes when i include any other record in which "a" is not present or is null.
All the records after convert record gets the attribute "a" as vanished.

Pls help!

Comment: Need more info about your ConvertRecord processors... what record reader is it using? what is the schema used? what record writer?

Comment: Is `a` a field in the record(s) or an attribute on the entire flow file?